# How to store bitmap image in file in sdcard?

Tags: android

```
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    if(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
    {
        cacheFile = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Android/data/"+this.getPackageName()+"/cache/");
        if(!cacheFile.exists())
        {
            cacheFile.mkdir();
        }
        try {
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(cacheFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Error", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

but I am getting error that mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.android.linegame/cache file not exist

Comment: Your mnt/sdcard/Android/data  doesn't  contain folder com.android.linegame/cache

Comment: did you give this permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: You using emulator or real device? if you using emulator 3.1 upward it has a bug.

Comment: use this line cacheFile = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/Android/data/"+this.getPackageName()+"/cache/"); instead of yours

Comment: Which versoin of Android you are using??

Answer (score 0):

Which versoin of Android you are using?? Because Android 2.2 contains folder "Android" in mnt/sdcard. But Android 4.0 version doesn't contain folder "Android".

Add following code:

```
cacheFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/Android/data/"+this.getPackageName()+"/cache/");
if(!cacheFile.exists()) {
    cacheFile.mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: Android 2.2 contains folder "Android" in mnt/sdcard. But Android 4.0 doesn't contain